# Performing Scoring Indicator : With principal component

Tags: pca, descriptive-statistics

iam trying to generate an engagement indicator from 5 variables which i feel that explained engaged behaviours in my application, for each specific user i will need to score it in an indicator so as to know his engagement with my application. So as to knowing the weights i should give to each variable for obtaining a final number (the number which i going to communicate as the final indicator) i used a principal component analysis. I am going to use the first principal component to know which are the weight i should give to each variable. (It is this logic ok ? i read in this post that it was a good way to know the weights to use https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_create_an_index_using_principal_component_analysis_PCA)

The result for my first principal components were

```
  variables        PC1        PC2
nrosessions  71076.978    901.025
  daysofuse  -5150.779  -6799.831
   searches -20780.789  18889.332
     poster -22750.892  -7161.112
     reply  -22394.516  -5829.414
```

So PC1 would be my weights for my final indicator, i am thinking to use it in this way

```
final_indicator = 71076.978 (nrosessions) + -5150.779 (daysofuse) + -20780.789 (searches) + -22750.892 (poster) + -22394.516 (reply)
```

I am having difficulties in intrepreting my final result base on the heavy negative weights in poster and repliers, which for my are the guys which i will like to weight much more in my indicator due that i think are those which are my engage with my application

Comment: What do the variables mean? Do you expect all of the variables to be positively correlated? You can swap all of the coefficient signs in a PCA and it still means the same thing, so perhaps nrosessions is negatively related with engagement and all of the other variables are positively related with engagement?

Comment: nrosessions : number of open session in the month , daysofuse : number of days used in the month the application , searches : how many time made searches complete in the application, poster: quantity of posting , reply: quantites of reply for a certain product . If i do that, i dont want to nro of session to weight in a negative way, because for me more nro of session is a more engage user but maybe with a less weight than a replier user

Comment: In that case there may be a problem. I suggest looking at the correlation matrix and looking at all pairwise scatter plots. That may highlight any problems with the data.